# OrmLite: executing stored procedure and mapping the result onto model does not work when attributes are used

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

What are the actual requirements for ORMLite to project result of the call to stored procedure onto the model. I have a class that has some attributes and it will not map output of the sp correctly. If I remove attributes then it does map it correctly. For example:

```
public class Test
{
   [Alias("InsuredId")]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
}
```

SP returns these columns: InsuredId, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial and some more.
If I have Alias attribute all properties are populated with null. If I remove attribute, then all are fine except the Id. Following is the actual code.

```
var  test =
        db.SqlList<Test>(
            "EXEC up_InsuredSearchTest @ItemId, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @Max_Search_Records",
            new
                {
                    ItemId = memberId,
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName,
                    DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.HasValue? dateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
                    Max_Search_Records = MAX_SEARCH_RECORDS
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an issue with ServiceStack. Value returned was an int but was mapped as string, and it was silently failing in ServiceStack, but error was logged. Error was not very informative, so I had to debug through ORMLite source to figure out what the problem was.